# nginx with multiple locations directives with subdomains

Tags: nginx, centos7

I am trying to implement something like that in the nginx conf:

subdomain

- sub.domain.com -> Serve html
- sub.domain.com/api -> proxy to port 3001
- **sub.domain.com/viewer -> serve another html**

subdomain2

- sub2.domain.com -> proxy to port 3000

The only route that doesn't work is the **viewer**, I get the html from the "location /". All other configurations work well.

I tried to move the viewer to the bottom then to the top and to the middle no matter what it doesn't work.

I use CentOS7. This is the configurations currently in the server:

```
events {
}
http {
    server {
            listen 80;
            listen [::]:80;
            server_name www.sub.domain.com subdomain.com;

            location /viewer {
                    root /opt/viewer/;
                    try_files $uri /index.html;
                    index index.html;
            }

            location / {
                    root /opt/client-bo/;
                    try_files $uri /index.html;
                    index index.html;
            }

            location /api {
                    proxy_pass "http://localhost:3001";
            }
    }
    server {
            listen 80;
            server_name www.sub2.domain.com sub2.domain.com;
            listen [::]:80;
            location / {
                    proxy_pass "http://localhost:3000";
            }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your viewer app located in the `/opt/viewer` directory and you want it to be available under the `/viewer` URI prefix, you should use `root /opt;` for the `location /viewer { ... }`. Check the difference between [`root`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) and [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) directives.

Next, the very last argument of the `try_files` directive is treated as the new URI to re-evaluate, so you `/index.html` being treated as the new URI going to be served with the `location / { ... }`. You should change that directive to

```
try_files $uri /viewer/index.html;
```