# Multiple Reverse Proxy and Hosting NginX

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

#### What I want to accomplish

I am attempting to build an nginx server that is a reverse proxy to two rest apis and host to an Angular app. I basically need to route requests `/api/v1/` to the server on port 5000, host the Angular app on `/app` and all other requests to the server listening on 8087. I realize that this is not the best way to do things, but i really wan to find out what i'm doing wrong and learn from my mistakes.

#### My Current configuration

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    server {
        listen 80;

        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        location ^~ /api/v1/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        }

        location ^~ /app/ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8087;
        }
    }
}
```

#### My Problem

I am following this [tutorial on the location directive](https://www.keycdn.com/support/nginx-location-directive) . When i go to `/app/` the application works normally and everything is fine. But when i try `/app/login` the request is proxied to the server on 8087. It was my undestanding that the `^~` modifier should match with the `/app/` and stop searching. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are using the `try_files` directive incorrectly. For your configuration it should be the `try_files $uri $uri/ /app/index.html`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69880178/7121513) answer for the explanation.

Comment: @IvanShatsky Thank you so much, i can't believe i didn't see this, such a foolish mistake - thanks again